# Aligning five text elements vertically on two separate lines

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, text

I'm looking to align five text elements from two separate lines vertically with one another so that the five elements on top act as labels for the text below them. I have tried to do so using `\hfill` and `\hspace*{\fill}`, but both simply fill the space on their specific line and didn't match the elements up to one another between lines.

I believe this could be done by somehow manually setting the text space as some percentage of the line (for instance, all set at 20%), but I'm not sure how this could be done.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This sounds somewhat like a linguistic gloss.  Another approach might call on `\tabbing`.  I'm sure that both these possibilities have been covered before.

Comment: Please post an image of what you're trying to achieve. A hand-drawn sketch would be fine.

Comment: see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cgloss4e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stack text with `stackengine`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\labelit[2]{\stackengine{.9\baselineskip}{#1}
  {\scriptsize\sffamily#2}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}
\begin{document}
\labelit{To be}{what}\quad
\labelit{or not}{is}\quad
\labelit{to be?}{this}\quad
\labelit{that is}{telling}\quad
\labelit{the question}{us?}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know Homer wrote that play.

Comment: The @DavidCarlisle doth protest too much, methinks!

Answer (score 0):

It definitely depends on how you want to use it. However, one way to apply it as below:

```
\begin{equation*}
    \underbrace{\text{top1}}_{\text{bottom1}} \quad 
    \underbrace{\text{top2}}_{\text{bottom2}} \quad 
    \underbrace{\text{top3}}_{\text{bottom3}} \quad 
    \underbrace{\text{top4}}_{\text{bottom4}} \quad 
    \underbrace{\text{top5}}_{\text{bottom5}} 
\end{equation*}
```

[image]